# Eslint analog for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, eslint

I used eslint for PHPStorm and WebStorm. Can I use eslint for Android Studio? If I can't, what analogs can I use?

Maybe I can use standart Android Studio tools? I want formatting my code every time when I save it automatically